# Implementing a Dart function with a variable number of parameters

Tags: javascript, flutter, algorithm, function, dart

I want to implement a sum function which gets not-determined (desired) number of parameters (here are numbers)

so I can use it like this

```
var sum = sumOfNumbers(2, 55, 66.5)
print(sum)
```

*** I don't want to use list as the parameter of the function. ***

[this is the JavaScript equivalent code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNGrL.jpg)